# C++ Composition with abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, optimization, composition

Lets say I have an abstract class that is expensive to create and copy:

```
class AbstractBase {
public:
    AbstractBase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; ++i) {
            values.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    virtual void doThing() = 0;

private:
    vector<int> values;
};
```

It has two subclasses `FirstDerived`:

```
class FirstDerived : public AbstractBase {
public:
    void doThing() {
        std::cout << "I did the thing in FirstDerived!\n";
    }

};
```

and `SecondDerived`:

```
class SecondDerived : public AbstractBase {
public:
    void doThing() {
        std::cout << "I did the thing in SecondDerived!\n";
    }
};
```

Further, I would like to make a class that utilizes `FirstDerived` or `SecondDerived` using composition (not aggregation). Meaning that I want `ComposedOfAbstractBase` to *own* whichever temporary is passed in. If I weren't using abstract classes in this class would look like: (in C++11)

```
class ComposedOfWhicheverDerived {
public:
    ComposedOfWhicheverDerived(AbstractBase abstract_base) : abstract_base(std::move(abstract_base)) {;}
private:
    AbstractBase abstract_base;
};
```

However, this does not work with abstract classes because I cannot ever create an instance of `AbstractBase`, even if I am careful about not passing in a temporary `AbstractBase`, like so:

```
ComposedOfWhicheverDerived a(FirstDerived());
```

To the compiler this is just as bad as:

```
ComposedOfWhicheverDerived b(AbstractBase());
```

Because I still have an instance of `AbstractBase` in the class declaration.

The next solution I came up with is:

```
class ComposedOfAbstractBase {
public:
    ComposedOfAbstractBase(AbstractBase&& abstract_base) : some_derived_instance(abstract_base) {;}

private:
    AbstractBase& some_derived_instance;
};
```

This works perfectly (even though I don't fully understand it)! Both of these instances are valid and work as intended:

```
ComposedOfAbstractBase a(FirstDerived());
ComposedOfAbstractBase b(SecondDerived());
```

It doesn't create a copy of whatever `AbstractBase` temporary is passed in, and storing a reference to an `AbstractBase` is allowed. Though at best the reference to an rvalue reference seems unclear: it does not convey that `ComposedOfAbstractBase` *owns* whichever temporary is passed in. In addition to that, it turns out that this solution seems to be sub-optimal. To show this I created this class:

```
class ComposedOfFirstDerived {
public:
    ComposedOfFirstDerived(FirstDerived first_derived) : first_derived(std::move(first_derived)) {;}

private:
    FirstDerived first_derived;
};
```

Which can only take in a `FirstDerived`, so we can apply the `std::move` to offload ownership of the temporary. I can make an instance like so:

```
ComposedOfFirstDerived c(FirstDerived());
```

Interestingly enough, this class consistently is 10% faster to create than `ComposedOfAbstractClass`.

Does anybody know what is going on here? Why is `ComposedOfFirstDerived` so much faster to create than `ComposedOfAbstractBase`? Is there a better way to do composition with abstract classes or am I stuck with a sub-optimal solution?

Sorry if this was a mouthful of a question. I appreciate anyone who takes the time to read through it and give a genuine answer, because I am beyond stumped!

Comment: The *sub-optimal* solution is entirely wrong. It doesn't own the temporaries.

Comment: What does own the temporaries then? Does it do the equivalent of creating a new pointer then never deleting it?

Comment: No, it's equivalent to holding a pointer to an invalidated memory area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ComposedOfAbstractBase` is not a solution. You're holding a dangling reference.

Since `AbstractBase` is, as the name suggests, abstract - you cannot hold one by value. You can only hold one by reference or by pointer. Since a reference cannot own the object, that leaves you with the pointer. And the modern way of owning a pointer is to use `unique_ptr`:

```
class ComposedOfAbstractBasePtr {
public:
    ComposedOfAbstractBasePtr(std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> p)
    : some_derived_instance(std::move(p))
    { }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> some_derived_instance;
};
```

Note that your `AbstractBase` does not have a virtual destructor. You should fix that.

Comment: How then do I initialize that? I can no longer do `ComposedOfAbstractBasePtr(FirstDerived())`. Do I have to create the unique_ptr to the object then pass it in? What stops me from deleting that ptr later due to carelessness?

Comment: @donutmonger You would do `make_unique<FirstDerived>()`. Or you can make a `unique_ptr` earlier and `move` it in. As long as you deal with `unique_ptr`s exclusively, you cannot carelessly delete it. You'd have to explicitly type `delete p.get();` which should be a red flag...

Comment: @donutmonger: `ComposedOfAbstractBasePtr(std::make_unique<FirstDerived>())` You cannot apply `delete` to a `unique_ptr`, and even if you could, you pass an unnamed temporary anyway. This cannot go wrong because of carelessness.

Comment: Thanks so much, it makes a lot more sense now!