# dynamic polymorphism not being implemented properly in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

i am trying to make a payroll system hierarchy and my base class of all is a abstract class and all the other classes inherited are concrete classes (classes that can be instantiated).. i have a pure virtual function earning() in my base class abstract base class employee.. the proper functionality of earning is provided in the derived classes depending on the type of employee whose earning is being calculated. I also have a virtual function in the abstract base class that is display information which is overridden in all the derived classes.
The class hierarchy goes like this

1. class employee;
2. class commissionEmployee : public employee;
3. class salariedEmployee : public employee;
4. class basePlusCommissionEmployee : public employee

the commission employee's overridden pure virtual function earning adds up the gross sales of the employee in a week with the commission rate and should return a double.

the salaried employee's overridden earning function only returns the salary that is earned by the employee as his/her salary is the only earning.

the basePlusCommissionEmployee means that a employee who has both things being added up in his/her earning function that is the salary of that employee and the commission that employee will earn from the sales he/she makes..
the problem that i a facing is that when i use a base class pointer to point at a derived class's object.. the dynamic polymorphism does get implemented but in the displayInformation function that alse overridden in each class, i do not get the total information.. it does not displays the name of the employee nor his/her earning. [image]
i have also posted an image that shows the output of the overridden displayInformation function of the salaried employee class.. other than name and social security number the only additional input salaried employee class asks for is the salary of that employee..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class employee
{
private:
    string name;
    string socialSecurityNumber;
public:
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    void setSSN(string);
    string getSSN();
    virtual double earnings() = 0;
    virtual void displayInformation();
};
void employee::setName(string argName)
{
    name = argName;
}
string employee::getName()
{
    return name;
}
void employee::setSSN(string argSSN)
{
    socialSecurityNumber = argSSN;
}
string employee::getSSN()
{
    return socialSecurityNumber;
}
void employee::displayInformation()
{
    cout <<"name: " <<getName()
    <<"Social security number: " <<getSSN();
}

class salariedEmployee : public employee
{
private:
    double salary;
public:
    void setSalary(double);
    double getSalary();
    virtual double earnings();
    virtual void displayInformation();
};
void salariedEmployee::setSalary(double argSalary)
{
    salary = argSalary;
}
double salariedEmployee::getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}
double salariedEmployee::earnings()
{
    //we will only return salary because that is the only earning of a salaried employee
    return salary;
}
void salariedEmployee::displayInformation()
{
    employee::displayInformation();
    cout <<"weekly salary: " <<getSalary();
}

class commissionEmployee : public employee
{
private:
    double commissionRate;
    double grossSales;
public:
    void setCommission(double);
    double getCommission();
    void setGrossSales(double);
    double getGrossSales();
    virtual double earnings();
    virtual void displayInformation();
};
void commissionEmployee::setCommission(double argCommission)
{
    commissionRate = argCommission;
}
double commissionEmployee::getCommission()
{
    return commissionRate;
}
void commissionEmployee::setGrossSales(double argSales)
{
    grossSales = argSales;
}
double commissionEmployee::getGrossSales()
{
    return grossSales;
}
double commissionEmployee::earnings()
{
    return (commissionRate * grossSales);
}
void commissionEmployee::displayInformation()
{
    employee::displayInformation();
    cout <<"\ncommission rate: " << getCommission()
    <<"\nweekly sales: " <<getGrossSales();
}

class basePlusCommissionEmployee : public commissionEmployee
{
private:
    double salary;
public:

    void setSalary(double);
    double getSalary();
    virtual double earnings();
    virtual void displayInformation();
};
void basePlusCommissionEmployee::setSalary(double argSalary)  
{
    salary = argSalary;
}
double basePlusCommissionEmployee::getSalary()
{
   return salary;
}
double basePlusCommissionEmployee::earnings()
{
    return (getSalary() + commissionEmployee::earnings());
}
void basePlusCommissionEmployee::displayInformation()
{
    employee::displayInformation();
    commissionEmployee::displayInformation();
    cout <<"salay: " <<salary;
    cout <<endl; 
}

int main()   
{
    int choice;
    double salary;
    string name, SSN;
    cout <<"choose\n1)salaried employee\n2)commission employee\n3)base plus salaried 
    employee\nenter: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout <<"enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout <<"enter SSN: ";
    cin >>SSN;
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        employee *pointerObj = new salariedEmployee;
        salariedEmployee obj;
        obj.setName(name);
        obj.setSSN(SSN);
        cout <<"enter weekly salary: ";
        cin >> salary;
        obj.setSalary(salary);
        system("cls");
        cout <<"total earning of this employee: " <<pointerObj->earnings();
        cout <<endl;
        pointerObj->displayInformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages, just copy/paste them as text.

Comment: There is no error.. their is some logical error.. i posted the image just in case if i weren't clear to explain the problem.. someone would just see the output and know whats going with the output

Comment: You seem to expect `pointerObj` to point to `obj`.

Comment: You're confusing your two different variables `pointerObj` and `obj`.

Comment: Apart from confusing two distinct objects, you produced a memory leak by not deleting `pointerObj` again (you could avoid that necessity by use of a smart pointer, e. g. `std::unique_ptr`)...

Comment: `name = std::move(argName);` would avoid one copy in favour of moving...

Comment: Thanks alot for the input.. i can't  believe i was literally confusing two distinct objects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct and different objects...

First you have the object pointed to by `pointerObj`, and the only thing you do with that object is to call its `displayInformation` function.

Then you have the `obj` object, which is where you set all values.

If you want to print all the data you set for `obj` then you need to call `displayInformation` on `obj` instead:

```
obj.displayInformation();
```

Otherwise you should set all the information on the object pointed to be `pointerObj` and don't have the variable `obj` at all.

Or a possible third solution:

```
employee *pointerObj = &obj;
```

Comment: I recommend that you try `using composition` rather than `using inheritance` for abstract classes. This thread discusses the topic @[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276484/c-composition-with-abstract-class ]. —CW